# How Do I Connect My Laravel Project[views] file to Route Auto Created with Jetstream?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I am actually following up on a Laravel course that uses Blade component template and the tutor coded the Login/Register/Dashboard, etc individually. I couldn't keep up with the coding and I sorted for a quicker way of adding those features.

That was how I discovered I can do those things with Jetstream. I installed Jetstream/Livewire and the above mentioned features were added automatically with a default **view/welcome.blade.php** connected to **Route/web.php**.

Now here is my problem. Because I still want to follow through with the course by using Blade template method, I deleted the defaulted **welcome.blade.php**(as the tutor did too), created two folders with a file respectively: **Layouts/app.blade.php** and **Posts/index.blade.php**.
On the **Route/web.php**, I changed the default **welcome** to **post.index** but it is not working. Here is the code on my Route:

```
Route::get('/post', function () {
    return Inertia::render('post.index', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
        'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
    ]);
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

And here is the error I got:

> InvalidArgumentException
> View [app] not found.
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/post

> app was not found.
> Are you sure the view exists and is a .blade.php file?

This is the screenshot of my editor to show the code and prove I have the view files.

[image: This is the screenshot of my editor to show the code and prove I have the view files]

**Edited** Here are the **index.blade.php** and **app.blade.php** as requested by @Prospero:
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you post your index.blade.php?

Comment: Hello sir, I just added the index.blade,php and app.blade.php. Thanks

Comment: look if your RouteServiceProvider or your middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated are redirecting to an undesired route, I don't work with Jetstream before but look at the config file too if there is any redirect property declared there